# Which of the ATI Dynamic Switchable Graphics are used when there is no "switching" utility?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, hp-pavilion, switchable-graphics

I have a ATI Dynamic switchable graphics on a HP Pavilion g7 (hp pavilion g7-1246ef) but it has no support in Win7 32-bit.

It seems that I have 2 VGA controllers:

- One on-CPU Intel for energy-efficiency
- One discrete card (an ATI/AMD Radeon HD 6470M in your case) for rendering.

[image]

The Intel driver provided Aero support and other options and the Windows update gives a generic driver for AMD but drivers from AMD and HP made for the switching part (including AMD Catalyst Control Center) are not working in this case. More on this (especially the comments) - [here](https://superuser.com/q/728953/162573).

I gave up for now but I am curious what happens meanwhile.

I know that the AMD Catalyst Control Center allows choosing manually the VGA or letting the applications choose which VGA to use. But what happens when there's no AMD Catalyst Control Center present?

Comment: When there is no AMD CCC present, the system cannot dynamicaly switch which GPU will be used.

Comment: @Ramhound - so, does this mean that only one is used? which one? and does this mean i can disable the other one?

Comment: If you have generic display drivers install for the AMD GPU and Intel drivers for the Intel GPU are installed, the Intel GPU is going to do most of the work.

Comment: Try first to verify your drivers, first via Windows Update in the optional section, then using [DriverMax](http://download.cnet.com/DriverMax/3000-18513_4-10572602.html?tag=bc). If this works, try again installing [AMD Catalyst Control Center](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download).

Comment: @harrymc - already did that... to see the full picture please look at the other questions [here](http://superuser.com/q/728953/162573) (also my answer there) and [here](http://superuser.com/q/792586/162573).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the tool call [OpenHardwareMonitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) and add the AMD Radeon HD to the gadget. if the GPU is not used you see this:

[image]

If the GPU is used you see the data of the GPU (Voltage, GPU/Mem speed, Temperature):

[image]

Is your AMD card used or the Intel?

Comment: bounty in 14 hours. i was able to test it because meanwhile i am able to use the  ATI Dynamic Switchable Graphics on my system. so, i can easily see if this app follows the setting in Catalyst Control Center and also I can use this app to see if CCC does what it says it does.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in [this thread](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/Problem-with-AMD-HD-7670M-and-CCC-at-HP-pavilion-g7-2210/td-p/2653339) was :

> Uninstall CCC software, restart pc, install only GPU drivers without CCC.
>   My laptop is working now like this - when I am on batery mode,
>   only intel is running, when I am on power supply only AMD is running.

You could also try using the [Unified Leshcat Drivers](http://leshcatlabs.net/unifl-unified-leshcat-drivers/).

Comment: I have tested the Leshcat drivers: this solution is pushing to clean all sign of video driver on the PC (close to impossible, because Win7 will automatically start updating video drivers when none is there!) then provides to farther clean with a special tool in safe mode (odd!), then, when running the package, it starts to un-pack and then the antivirus says it needs to clean the virus, and after/if ignoring that, i get the message "you do not have the minimum hardware requirements".

Comment: " when I am on batery mode, only intel is running, when I am on power supply only AMD is running": **how do you see** which one is running?

Answer (score 0):

Quote from Tom's guide :

> As the name indicates, the Catalyst Control Center acts as the central
>   hub for all options and features relating to an AMD video card. By
>   launching CCC, users are given access to various features: display
>   management, digital control, 3D enabling, color adjustment and
>   overdriving.
>
> ```
>                          ...
> ```
>
> While the Windows OS allows users to control some of these options,
>   the AMD Catalyst Control Center gives access to even greater levels of
>   customization and display performance enhancements. Whether you use
>   multiple monitors with varying resolution capabilities or multimedia
>   software, CCC can control all display functionality.

To sum the Quote, options can be accessed without the CCC but it may be hard to find. You could use some **hacks** or **special software** to change hidden settings.

In most computers, there's a bus called "Plug and Play". It checks for your hardware and ensures the compatibility. It does the correct configuration to your hardware. From some online definitions : *It detects your hardware and chooses the correct one to use for a service*.

Plug and Play should be enough if you need applications to work appropriately.

Plug and Play has evolved a lot. On modern computer, it should do its work correctly with no mistakes !