# Is there any way to tell which graphics processor is working in a laptop?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

I have a Dell Inspiron N5010 laptop which has both a discrete GPU (ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650) and an integrated GP (Intel HD Graphics). A few days ago I started to get BSOD with the atikmpag.sys 0x00000116 error. In the device manager I had stopped the ATI driver and now I can use my laptop. In the display properties I read that now it uses the VgaSave driver.

My question is: is this driver runs in the integrated GP, or in the discrete GPU?
Is there any way to tell?

Thank you.

---

**UPDATE:**
This is from the Dell Inspiron N5010 Setup Guide:

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2:**
This is what Adapter Properties Window shows:

[image]

---

**UPDATE 3:**
I am now really confused. I have been running my laptop for about 5 hours on the VgaSave driver, with ATI driver stopped in the Device Manager. As Fleet Command has suggested, I assumed that the VgaSave driver was running on the inegrated GP.
Could you please see the attached picture and tell me why the discrete GPU heats up?

[image]

I also downloaded the latest version of the OpenHardwareMonitor, as suggested in the answer for this question ([Which of the ATI Dynamic Switchable Graphics are used when there is no "switching" utility?](https://superuser.com/questions/729085/which-of-the-ati-dynamic-switchable-graphics-are-used-when-there-is-no-switchin)), and its readings do not seem to be reliable as to whether the discrete GPU is engaged or not. That makes the accepted answer **invalid**.

[image]

Also, my system is different from the system in the question because I do not have the integrated GP listed in the Device Manager. So - different system and no valid answer = **not a duplicate**.

---

**UPDATE 4:** 
I made some more screenshots, hope that may help. I can not post images, so I can only provide the links.
 
This is DirectX Diagnostic Tool (DxDiag) output, it is not in English, but if something needs explanation, I will translate: [imgur.com/a/rdz2u](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbjvE.jpg)

This is GPU-Z output:
[imgur.com/a/mUX7Y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gieu7.jpg) 
[imgur.com/a/1VuAh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bjNJ.jpg) 

And this is from the Device Manager, I put some minor translation (in red): [imgur.com/a/6LZOV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRYv6.jpg)

The laptop CPU is Intel Core i5 M480 2.67 GHz 
Thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: "Could you please see the attached picture and tell me why the discrete GPU heats up?" - The temperature of the iGPU should be near/close to the temperature of the CPU, since its intergrated into the CPU, a few degrees +/- from your CPU temperature isn't unheard of.  In other words your iGPU temperature is well within it's specifications.  [Besides the program is reporting the temperature on the AMD GPU not the Intel GPU.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/B9Te4.png) you have the wrong GPU circled.

Comment: Have you installed the Intel Display Drivers?  You have not provided enough information to identify the actual Intel GPU your using (Intel HD Graphics describes several generations of GPUs including a generation ltierally called `Intel HD Graphics`).

Comment: "So - different system and no valid answer = not a duplicate." - I don't agree with this conclusion, the simple fact is that, the answer still appliciable to your situation.

Comment: Ramhound, you did not understand. If we assume, that the VgaSave driver is running on the iGP, then ATI should not heat up. And ATI is stopped. Concerning your question, I never installed any video drivers and I do not know how to identify the Intel iGP, since it is not in the Device Manager. If you believe that the provided answer is valid in my situation, then tell me where the VgaSave driver is running?

Comment: If you identify your CPU, with only that knowlege, I can identify your Intel iGPU.  If you believe the iGPU is using the VgaSave driver, you should prove it, provide your dxdiag report (in english) that indicates that.

Comment: [Display Drivers for Intel® Core™ Processors on 64-bit Windows 7* and Windows Embedded Standard 7*](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22394/Display-Drivers-for-Intel-Core-Processors-on-64-bit-Windows-7-and-Windows-Embedded-Standard-7-)

Comment: Thank you for the link, Ramhound. My CPU is Intel Core i5 M480 2.67 GHz (2 cores). If ATI GPU is stopped in the Device Manager, where else the VgaSave driver could possibly run? How can I get the dxdiag report?

Comment: Update your question.  I shouldn't have had to read your comments, to an answer, to identify your CPU.  You don't know about about `dxdiag`?  **Can you do some research on that before I answer that question?**

Comment: You don't have to bother at all, nobody forces you. I am doing research of my own and I also ask people who know the subject, which is also a kind of research.

Comment: I know the subject, but I can't identify which Intel drivers you should use, if you don't identify which CPU you have in the question body itself.  Just run dxdig and post the report....

Comment: Could you install GPU-Z and tell us what shows? According to your processor, you should have _Intel® HD Graphics_ appearing in the device manager. This is confirmed going to the [Dell's drivers website](http://www.dell.com/support/home/es/es/esdhs1/product-support/product/inspiron-15-intel-n5010/drivers), where you have booth drivers from Intel and ATI.

Comment: @jgorosdev - presence of the driver for the device in section for the given model is not equivalent to certainty it is in that model. Only Service tag in Dell's case can tell exactly the system config and suggest appropriate drivers (but still not reliably).  *and his dog* already told us that this is the case - admittedly, in a comment, not updating question.

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks for the help, guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important for the troubleshooting to know WHEN the error appears. What do you do on your computer when it happens? Also, do you see **both** GPUs in the device manager or just one VgaSave? At this moment it can be anything from failing GPU to corrupted driver(s). Also, Windows uses VgaSave driver **because** you stopped the ATI driver to manage the ATI GPU in any way. You can identify the device this driver manages by going in to device Properties, click on tab "Details" and from the drop-down box select "Hardware IDs", which is usually second down. It should be in English or very nearly literal translation.

It will give you string like:

*PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1912&SUBSYS_06BB1028&REV_06*

which you can try to identify the device with [here](http://pcidatabase.com/).

As for further troubleshooting when the error happens...

Has anything changed before the error started? Drivers update, upgraded hardware, unexpected system freeze or black screen or anything? Is there anything else that happens in the system - errors, warnings, etc - which do not cause BSOD?

EDIT:

Now things get interesting. This laptop has 1st gen i5 CPU, which **should** have onboard GPU (but please confirm - there are newer models with different CPU). But we have to be sure. Is there an BIOS option disabling it? If yes, enable it and see if you have Intel HD appearing in DevManager (yes, you should have **TWO** display adapters listed there if all is ok, second being ATI). If not, you have a laptop with just one GPU, which is the ATI.

In that latter case and taking into consideration your info about BSOD it seems that indeed the Radeon has breathed it's last.

EDIT 2:

After going through some data on Dell n5010 system available on dell websites there are two important bits of information:

1. This laptop comes with **either** IGPU or ATI. There is no hybrid graphics available for the system - Radeon 5650 does not and will not support it
2. And even if, the Intel graphics most commonly reported in this model is Intel 4500MHD, which comes with chipset...

In other words: I don't know what is going on, but it looks like with this laptop model you got either IGPU or ATI. Not both. Not sure it's how Dell chose it or ATI can't do it.

EDIT 3: N5010 with ATI discrete graphics is both not designed by Dell to be switchable and Radeon 5650 doesn't support it anyway. However, with soldering equipment one can bypass the faulty ATI chip and system will then work with IGPU enabled. But this is amateur work to say the least.

So, it looks like the ATI chip is either faulty or the driver is corrupted. I recommend uninstalling all ATI drivers and any ATI software either manually or using [ATI Uninstaller](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Clean-Uninstall-Utility.aspx). When that's done do an extra reboot and then install driver provided by Dell on the product support page **ONLY**. If that works - all is well. If you're back to not working device in Device Manager it means the chip is failing. This is first and final warning you get before it stops working completely and you're left with laptop withe either black screen after turning it on or beeping error code(s).

Comment: Hi, AcePL. Thanks for the answer. What I am trying to figure out now is if my discrete GPU is dead and all the work is performed by the integrated GP, or if the VgaSave driver is running on the discrete GPU? As for the BSODs, now I am getting them every time I reboot the laptop with the ATI driver enabled. When the ATI driver is stopped, the laptop runs Ok, no errors, no warnings, except that I get only VGA resolution, and no sleep option. Which kind of sucks. In the device manager I got only one video adapter listed - ATI. No mention of the VgaSave.

Comment: The only suitable string I have found in the Details is "\Device\00000045". The first BSOD had happened unexpectedly. I was watching something on Youtube.

Comment: @andhisdog Please see edit to the answer.

Comment: According to the Setup Guide, the laptop does have an integrated GP (I attached a picture). There are no BIOS options to enable/disable it. Only one adapter is listed in the Device manager - ATI. When I enable the ATI driver, the Adapter Properties Window displays all the information about the ATI GPU. But if I disable the driver, no information about GPU is displayed. The laptop is stable with the ATI driver disabled, no errors.

Comment: I just ran Dell Diagnostics, first two pases it reported no errors, on the third pass it reported an error reading from the video memory. That was with the ATI driver enabled.

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer, and now it shows -1, and does not go back. Maybe it's a curse?

Comment: @andhisdog - if you downvoted it in the first place then you need to un-downvote. Not upvote. But no worries.
Try installing drivers from: http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-15-intel-n5010/drivers, and go all the way down to **Video** section.  Be sure you uninstalled all previous versions first, though. Often dell drivers are not same as generic ones from manufacturer. They may clash. Also, Windows 7 may not recognize the Intel HD without drivers, so use installers for both GPUs

Comment: Thank you. When I enter the service tag, only one video driver is suggested by Dell - the ATI driver. I am very sceptical about it, but I'll give it a try. I have no idea how I can substitute the VgaSave driver though, since the Intel HD GP is not even in the Device Manager.

Comment: @andhisdog - Ok then. question: what CPU the system has? Or if you feel you can share the service tag. Or do it here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52306/discussion-is-there-any-way-to-tell-which-graphics-processor-is-working-in-a-la

Comment: I updated some images in my question. The CPU in the laptop is Intel Core i5 M480 (2 cores) 2.67 GHz. I am kind of wary to post the Service tag. If it is of use, I can give you all the necessary tech details concerning the laptop.

Comment: We don't need the service tag, don't post it, totally not required to help you.  Updating your question with which CPU you have should be done

Comment: @Ramhound - for CPU yes, but I'm thinking there's something else in there that would explain it. Retrospect: looks like I'm right - CPU is right one, so all should be ok but it's not.

Comment: @andhisdog - please see updated answer.

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks for the help, AcePL.

Comment: @andhisdog - And I've updated my answer.

Comment: You are probably right about iGP being non-functional in this model. As to the failing GPU, I see different possibilities. It could be a failing VRAM chip and the GPU itself might still be Ok. Another alternative - a partial loss of contact in the BGA, and then BGA reflow might fix the problem. I am inclined to think that this is hardware problem, although I will check the drivers anyway to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Right-click on your desktop and select "Screen resolution"
2. Click on the hyperlink that says "Advanced settings"
3. In the dialog box that appears, under the Adapter Type section, read the name of the component that is giving you picture.

Comment: Hi, Fleet Command. Thanks for the answer. In the Adapter Type section all the parameters are set to "inaccessible".

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of it?

Comment: Sure I can, but it is not in English, so nobody will understand what it says. But, believe me, it gives absolutely no information about the adapter. Probably, the VgaSave driver to blame.

Comment: Nevertheless, please post the screenshot of the Advanced setting dialog box anyway. I am consulting a couple of Microsoft engineers who can probably help and they insist on seeing a screenshot.

Comment: I added a screenshot, hope that may help.

Comment: They say CPU's integrated graphics

Comment: Thank you. If it is not too much trouble, could you please ask them if there is any way to replace the generic VgaSave driver for the integrated GP with something a little bit more advanced (as compared to VGA)?

Comment: Sorry. They are gone. But I imagine you should install an Intel Integrated GPU driver. That's what I did with my system. Sorry if I couldn't be of any help.

Comment: That's Ok, thank you for your help. I have no idea how to do that, so I probably post that as a separate question.