# GPU AMD radeon not working but installed. Only Intel Hd graphics

Tags: drivers, gpu

I have laptop- lenovo b51 80lm00w7ck, there is AMD Radeon R5 M330 in it. Problem is I installed driver for it. (everything done properly).

Then if I run System monitor and record while playing game my AMD Radeon is still on 0%.When I right click my desktop it shows only AMD Radeon Setting , there are no options on applications like run with this GPU.

Then I downloaded Luxmark. Luxmark software also recognized only Intel Intergrated graphics in tests. I am sure my driver is installed good , but dont know what could be bad. Maybe it fights with Visual Studio 2017 ? It seems like it is installed, but never turn on. I AM OUT OF IDEAS :-(.

Comment: in amd settings change the profile to "high performance" of the exe. now the AMD card is used.

Comment: i ve done this , but still if i run system monitor , record while play games, there is still 0% usage of graphic card amd radeon

Comment: try the [OpenHardwareMonitor](https://superuser.com/a/792830/174557), maybe your tools displays it wrong.