# How can I tell which graphics card my computer is using/how can I change it?

Tags: windows, laptop, graphics-card

I was looking into buying a game/figure out why another was running so slowly when I realized that I have two display adapters listed in my device manager. I am using a laptop.

One is an AMD Radeon R7 M260 (not sure how good that is, can anyone let me know?), and the other is Intel(R) HD Graphics Family.

I don't know which one my computer is using, though I'd obviously like it to use the Radeon one. How can I find out which one is in use, and how can I change it?

Comment: Is this a laptop or a desktop? Are you using an internal display?

Comment: Laptop. I don't know what you mean by internal display...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I assume it's internal display. Like... on my screen

Comment: If its a laptop.  Are you using an external monitor?

Comment: No, it's just one laptop and I'm using the laptop screen.

Comment: You have both the current Intel and AMD drivers installed?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got a laptop with switchable graphics . . . the system uses the Intel video for day to day stuff, and the switches and uses the Radeon for more demanding stuff (3d, games, etc).

The AMD Catalyst application should let you manually configure which card is used for which application if you don't like the defaults, as well as to monitor which card is being used.

Similar question: [How to install AMD driver for ATI Dynamic Switchable Graphics in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/728953/how-to-install-amd-driver-for-ati-dynamic-switchable-graphics-in-windows-7)